# is ternary operator usable for the following?

Tags: c, break, ternary-operator

just wondering if, for the following code lines, it is possible to replace using a ternary operator:

```
if( current->chbits[i] != '\0')
   printf("%c\n",current->chbits[i]);
else
   break;
```

If so, how would I parse it correctly?

Comment: I believe you know, the `break;` is not meant for the `else` condition, right? There needs to be an enclosing loop.

Comment: your sample doesn't compile, please show a more complete snippet

Comment: Thanks for quick follow-up.  I failed to check that reference as it said "C++". I'll know better next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have break in a ternary operator.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642693/why-cant-i-use-a-break-statement-inside-a-ternary-conditional-statement-in-c) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is used to evaluate an **expresson** conditionally:

```
result = condition ? first : second;
```

In your example is no conditional **expression** but an conditional **statement**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can replace the code with ternary operator by making some modifications to eliminate the `break` statement.

```
for(int i=0, int flag=1 ;flag!=0; i++){
    flag=(current->chbits[i]!='\0') ? printf("%c\n",current->chbits[i]) : 0;
}
```

Here `flag` won't be zero since `printf()` returns the number of characters successfully written on the output. When `current->chbits[i] != '\0'` becomes false `flag` is set to `0` and `for` terminates as per the condition `flag!=0`.