# if statement with "?" operator and break java

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

i can't find anywhere how to do methods with ? operator.
only what i know:

```
boolean something = (!again) ? true : false;
```

this returns me true or false, but if i have if method with break ? like this:

```
if(!again){
break;
}
```

can i do that too with ? operator ? or do you know better way ?
i have this method in while loop.

I dont know what to say more about that .. just that i canť find that. i was looking almost everywhere. Thank you

Thanx for reply <3

Comment: you can't (and shouldn't) do it using **ternary** operator

Comment: What's wrong with the if-statement?

Comment: `break` doesn't represent any value so it can't be used as such. It is like you would like to write `2+break` it makes no sense to allow it. Possibly related: [Why break cannot be used with ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37855337) (although it is not about Java)

Comment: you can make single-line if statements concise like this: `if (!again) break;`

Comment: What precisely you want?

Comment: @CommonMan I think they want to replace every `if` statement with ternary operator so that the code looks *cool*

Comment: This feels like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Why are you using a `break` in the first place?  Why do you think that mixing in the ternary operator (`?`) will be helpful?  In short, what is the *actual* problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: `break` is not a type_variable it's just an instruction used in conjunction with `for` or `switch`.(as @Pshemo mentioned). `?` is related to ternary operator which require a `type_var` to store the appropriate result. (in your case `boolean` is the type_var returned by `?`)

Comment: ALso `boolean something = (!again) ? true : false;` is overly wordy. Just do `boolean something = !again;`, it gives the same result.

Comment: if you have the method in a while loop, using if statement is the best way. ? ternary operator should be used when you want to assign a value to something like foo. String foo = (!again) ? "yes" : "no";

Comment: @ruslan - Where does this oft-quoted falsehood come from about the conditional operator only being allowed on the right-hand side of an assignment?  You can use it anywhere an expression is permitted. This is legal Java: ```p("%d", 1+(x>0 ? 3 : 0)*5);``` though in questionable taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **conditional operator** is used as part of an *expression*. So

```
  x ? y : z
```

is an expression.  You can use it anywhere an expression is called for. However,

```
  if (some_condition) some_action;
```

is a *statement*, and generally speaking, expressions and statements are not interchangeable. So if you're trying to get rid of the `if` statement, there is no way to do that with `?:`

On the other hand, `some_condition` is a (boolean) expression, so you *could* write:

```
 if (x ? y : z) some_action;
```

as long as x, y, z are themselves boolean subexpressions. So in your original terms, this is legal:

```
if (!again ? true : false)
     break;
```

But it's redundant and reduces to

```
 if (!again)
     break;
```

so there is negative value in writing it using the `?:` operator.

Answer (score 1):

`break;` is a statement. In java, statements and expressions cannot ordinarily be mixed, although a few things (assignments, unary increment/decrement expressions, constructor calls, and method invocations) are both.

the ternary operator works only with expressions.

It's as simple as that. break **is not an expression**, and the 'a' and 'b' in `cond ? a : b` **must be** expressions.

`if (!again) break;` is the only way.