# Check if Array element is not null in one line C#

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, continue, null-check

I got a `neighbor` array (consisting of Tile objects), that always has the length of 4, regardless if all elements are filled or not. I want to scan through that array and change the color of a PB contained in the Tile if that element / position is not null. I can do this via a standard `if neighbors[i] = null` check using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Neighbors.Count(); i++)
{
    if (Neighbors[i] != null)
       Neighbors[i].TilePB.Backcolor = Color.Red;
    else
       continue; // just put that here for some more context.
}
```

But I was wondering if I could do this in one line, similar to using the ? operator. I've tried using a ternary operator, but I can't `continue` using one (ternary statement I tried: `Neighbors[i] != null ? /* do something */ : continue`, source to why it doesn't work: [Why break cannot be used with ternary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855337/why-break-cannot-be-used-with-ternary-operator)).

Is there another way to check if an element of an array is null, only using one line (preferably without using a hack)?

Comment: You need to put context example of what you are trying to do to that object because there are many ways to do so. If it's a method you are trying to call for example you could do `Neighbors[i]?.MyMethod();`

Comment: You could also use the [null condition operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

Comment: Added some extra context. I need to change the backgroundcolor of a picturebox contained in a Tile object (the neighbor). the reason why I didn't get the ? operator to work is because I set the color right there and then, instead of calling a non-grouped method.

Comment: Have you not considered why you have to iterate through the neighbours to change the background colour? Did the neighbours magically appear? I think not. So why not set the background colour of the neighbour at the time you are making it?

Comment: I was building a small method to debug the neighbors - check if everything works properly - by calling this method on click. The color does get set on creation, but I wanted to check the neighbors of specific tiles (since some were acting a bit funky).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use linq for that:

```
foreach (var item in Neighbors.Where(n => n != null))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
neighbors.Where(x => x != null).ToList().ForEach(x => DoSomething(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need the return value of your action use select

```
var result = neighbors.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => MyAction(x)).ToList();
```